# Possibility to load video without extension from StreamingAssets?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to load video file to video player without specifying the name and extension? Or at least not the extension of the video file.

```
vp.url = Application.streamingAssetsPath + "/Video/" + "VideoFile.mp4";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the [`url`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer-url.html) expects an URL or a System path.

> The file or HTTP URL that the VideoPlayer reads content from.
>
> File URLs are filesystem paths that are either absolute on the platform or relative to the Player root.

A valid system path includes the extension of a file if it has one.

---

You could however use [`Directory.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles) in order to find files by partial name in a given folder like

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

private string FindVideoFile(string folderPath, string partialFileName)
{
    if(!Directory.Exists(folderPath)
    {
        Debug.LogError($"The folder {folderPath} does not exist!", this);
        return null;
    }

    var result = Directory.GetFiles(folderPath, partialFileName + "*", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly).FirstOrDefault();

    return result;
}
```

And use it like

```
var folder = Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Video");
var fileName = "VideoFile";

var fullPath = FindVideoFile(folder, fileName);
if(!fullPath.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    vp.url = fullPath;
}
else
{
    Debug.LogError($"No file called {fileName} was found in folder {folder} ", this);
    return;
}
```

---

*Typed on smartphone but I hope the idea gets clear*

Comment: This is not the correct answer to this question. This is an Unity3D question. The VideoPlayer the user mentions don't seem to support videos without the extension. The user is asking if there is a way to go over this issue. However, I don't think there is. Video Player Doc: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Video.VideoPlayer.html

Comment: @Lucas I know this is about Unity .. otherwise why should I use `Debug.Log` in my code snippets? Did you read the question? It was: "Is it possible to provide only the filename without an extension?" .. so the answer I gave is: "No" since the file path always includes a file extension. I provided a further way of how to only provide a filename and let the code search if there is any file with this name regardless of the extension. Of course it is up to OP to check whether the found files are valid video files ...

Comment: sorry if I sounded rude, wasn't my intention! The actual question is: 'Is there a way to load video file to video player without specifying the name and extension?' Since the user wrote the URL code correctly. I understood the problem must be related to loading files on the VideoPlayer that don't have extension, rather than a string/path issue. For example "C:\\file" or 'http://server.com/file', imagine the file content and path being valid. How to load without renaming the file (sometimes it's not possible to rename)? There is a similar question on the Unity forums, with no answer.